# Botões não aparecem no WindowBuilder e problemas para deixar de adicionar botão num arrayList

Tags: java

eu estou com um problema:eu não consigo saber a frase que está no botão dado o momento que a "cor" está passando por ele. queria saber a frase que está no botão quando este muda de cor.
oUTRO QUESTIONAMENTO: se eu coloco esse trecho de código dentro de addBotao da classe aluno:

```
for (int i = 0; i < botoes.size(); i++) { 
System.out.println(botoes.get(i).getValor()); 
System.out.println(botoes.size());
 }
```

No método addBotão, da classe AlunoCliente, não estou conseguindo entender porque a saída está repetindo valores. Gostaria de saber porque a saída repete o nome dos botões? Porque não aparece uma única vez e desta forma: NÃO ENTENDI; PODE REPETIR; PODE FALAR MAIS DEVAGAR; ESTOU ENTENDENDO; NÃO; MAIS OU MENOS. Porque? Ele repete os nomes, a saída é desta forma: NÃO ENTENDI; NÃO ENTENDI (REPETIDO), Assim por diante.

package visao;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class AlunoCliente extends JFrame {

private JPanel jPanel1;
private ArrayList<Botao> botoes = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<BtnOp> opcoes = new ArrayList<>();

public AlunoCliente() {

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(1500, 800);

jPanel1 = new JPanel();
setContentPane(jPanel1);
jPanel1.setLayout(null);
jPanel1.setLayout(null);

// DO JEITO QUE ESTÁ AQUI NÃO APARECE NO WINDOWBUILDER
addBotao("frase1", 57, 569, 306, 41);
addBotao("frase2", 392, 627, 306, 41);
addBotao("frase3", 57, 627, 306, 41);
addBotao("frase4", 392, 569, 306, 41);

setVisible(true);
}

private void addBotao(String frase, int x, int y, int largura, int altura) {
Botao b = new Botao(frase, jPanel1);
b.getBotao().setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
botoes.add(b);
jPanel1.add(b.getBotao());
 for (int i = 0; i < botoes.size(); i++) { 
System.out.println(botoes.get(i).getValor()); 
System.out.println(botoes.size());
 } 

}
public ArrayList<Botao> getBotoes() {
return botoes;
}
public ArrayList<BtnOp> getOpcoes() {
return opcoes;
}
}
```

package visao;

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Botao {
private JButton botao;
private String valor;
private JPanel painel;

public Botao(String frase, JPanel painel){
    this.painel = painel;
    this.botao = new JButton(frase);
    this.botao.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 25));
    this.valor = frase;
}

public JButton getBotao() {
    return botao;
}
public String getValor() {
    return valor;
}
}
```

package visao;

```
import java.awt.Button;

public class BtnOp {
private Button btn;
private int op;

public BtnOp(Button btn, int op) {
    this.btn = btn;
    this.op = op;
}

public Button getBtn() {
    return btn;
}

public int getOp() {
    return op;
}
}
```

package controle;

```
import visao.Botao;
import visao.BtnOp;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class ControllerPainel extends Thread {

    private ArrayList<Botao> botoes = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<BtnOp> opcoes = new ArrayList<>();
    private int totalBotoes;
    private boolean piscou;

    public ControllerPainel(boolean piscou, ArrayList<Botao> botoes, ArrayList<BtnOp> op) {
        this.botoes = botoes;
        this.piscou = piscou;
        this.totalBotoes = this.botoes.size();
        this.opcoes = op;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        // inicia a varredura dos botÃµes
        for (int indice = 0; indice < this.totalBotoes; indice++) {
            this.limpaBotoes();
            this.limpaBtnOp();

            // BotÃ£o da vez
            JButton botao = botoes.get(indice).getBotao();
            // altera a cor do botÃ£o
            botao.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

            try {
                // para no botÃ£o
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControllerPainel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            // VerificaÃ§Ã£o do Ãºltimo valor
            if (indice == (totalBotoes - 1)) {
                indice = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    /* ALTERANDO TODOS OS BOTÃ•ES PARA PADRÃƒO */
    private void limpaBotoes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalBotoes; i++) {
            JButton b = botoes.get(i).getBotao();
            b.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }
    }

    // limpa os botÃµes de opÃ§Ãµes
    private void limpaBtnOp() {
        for (int i = 0; i < opcoes.size(); i++) {
            Button b = opcoes.get(i).getBtn();
            b.setBackground(new Color(32, 185, 232));
        }
    }

}
```

package controle;

```
import visao.AlunoCliente;

public class ControleAlunoCliente {

private AlunoCliente ac;
private ControllerPainel painelController;
private boolean piscou;

public ControleAlunoCliente(AlunoCliente ac) {
    this.ac = ac;

    this.painelController = new ControllerPainel(piscou, this.ac.getBotoes(), ac.getOpcoes());
    this.painelController.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ControleAlunoCliente c = new ControleAlunoCliente(new AlunoCliente());
}
}
```

Comment: Qualquer componente gerado dinamicamente não irá aparecer no windowbuilder. Não dependa da visualização dele, é apenas para te dar uma noção de como a tela fica.

Comment: Não entendi qual é a duvida. Se quer adicionar os botoes sem arraylist, basta remover todas as funções q envolvam o arraylist e criar os botoes diretamente em `AlunoCliente`. Porém, você terá mais dificuldades em navegar pelos botões, já que a referencia deles não estará agrupada em lugar nenhum, do seu código.

Comment: se eu adicionar diretamente, não consigo fazer com que a cor passe por cada botão. porque da forma que está, a cada intervalo de segundo a cor do botão muda. Mas se eu adicionar um a um, não consigo fazer com que mude a cor

Comment: Então deixa como tá uai. Eu particulamente acho que essa forma q vc fez tá ótima, ainda mais se a quantidade de botoes que voce for  usar forem muitos e gerados dinamicamente. Usando as listas vc consegue manter a referencia de cada um e manipula-los isoladamente e de forma rapida quando for preciso :)

Comment: Por exemplo, eu estou com um problema:eu não consigo saber a frase que está no botão dado o momento que a "cor" está passando por ele. queria saber a frase que está no botão quando este muda de cor.

Comment: e outra, se eu coloco esse trecho de código dentro de addBotao da classe aluno:
 for (int i = 0; i < botoes.size(); i++) {
      
      System.out.println(botoes.get(i).getValor());
      System.out.println(botoes.size());
   
  } 
PQ A SAÍDA DA COMO SE OS BOTÕES TIVESSEM SE DUPLICANDO?

Comment: Recomendo q reformule a pergunta com essa nova duvida e edite o código tambem que simule este problema pra gente tentar te ajudar.

Comment: REFORMULEI A PERGUNTA